# PrintDocumentAdapter without onLayout() - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, pdf

I have an android app which generates pdf thanks to a PrintDocumentAdapter. It works fine but now i would like to generate the pdf without seeing the onLayout(), i don't need to change the settings of the pdf so the preview is useless for me and I need to generate 3-4 pdf without the preview each time.

Is it possible ?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english :)